# Error 503 unable to get issuer certificate Fastly CDN

Tags: ssl-certificate, cdn, fastly

I am trying to configure Fastly CDN for my website and as per the requirements of Fastly, I have updated the TLS CA certificate, TLS client certificate and TLS client key in .pem format. However, when I try to access the domain, I get an error "Error 503 unable to get issuer certificate" even though I have provided the necessary certificates. I downloaded the respective certificates from "/etc/ssl/private" from within the ubuntu machine present which consists of "SSLCertificateKeyFile (TLS client key), SSLCertificateFile (TLS client certificate), SSLCertificateChainFile (TLS CA certificate)". Please advise on where I am missing out on the config part.

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to support@fastly.com

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the intermediate cert. Something like:

```
openssl s_client -servername <yourdomain> -connect <yourorigin>:443 < /dev/null | openssl x509 -text
```

can tell you what is happening.